# How can you write an algorithm to properly fill a circle using lines from the center?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, processing, fill

Currently I try to write code for calculating the parts of the screen you can see and those who can't because of objects that block light in 2d, like in Among Us:
[image: Among Us and the parts of the screen you can see]

The code should run on a processor with very low specs (at least in 2020), the C64. On such a simple CPU it's not possible to do such complex math fast enough for a game, so I came up with an idea: First of all, I make everything tile based, that makes processing easier and also means that I can just change entire characters or their color cells. Then I just write code for the PC in Processing (that's a coding language similar to Java but easier to use) to calculate how rays of light would move (the following graphic should make that more understandable), first just with a rectangle (and a single quadrant):

[image: Rectangle filled by rays]

Then I wrote some completely messy assembler code for using the recorded coordinates to just keep filling the tiles with an inverted character based on the number of the ray currently being drawn on the ray until they hit an object (/ the tile it wants to fill is not inverted and not a space) and then just go to the next ray. I reduced the radius to 7 so it just takes up 256 bytes, useful for ASM. And that totally worked, I was able to fix every single bug and the result was quite impressive, since I needed to add pause statements or everything ran so fast that you couldn't see anything.

[image: Light demo 1][image: Light demo 2]

After that worked, I tried it with a circle, setting the points using this code:

```
int pointNum = ceil(radius * PI * 2); // calculates the circumference
for(int i = 0;i < pointNum;i++){
  float angle = map(i, 0, pointNum, 0, PI*2);
  setPixel(sin(angle) * radius, cos(angle) * radius);
}
```

I previously used the Bresenham circle algorithm but that didn't quite work so I tried a more simple way. So ...

[image: Circle]

All the marked black tiles never get hit by any light, which is a pretty big issue, because it wouldn't make much sense in a game that you just can't see those tiles. The code I used, written in [Processing](https://processing.org/), is:

```
float[] xPoints = new float[0];
float[] yPoints = new float[0];
float[] xPointsT;
float[] yPointsT;
float[] xPointsHad = new float[0];
float[] yPointsHad = new float[0];
int pos = 0;
float interpolPos = 0;

int radius = 12;
float tileSize = 800.0 / (2*radius+1);

String output = "  !byte ";
int pointNum = ceil(radius * PI * 2);
void setup() {
  size(800, 800);
  frameRate(60);
  xPointsT = new float[0];
  yPointsT = new float[0];
  /*for(int i = 0;i <= radius;i++){
    setPixel(radius, i);
    setPixel(i, radius);
  }*/ //Uncomment this and comment the next 4 lines to get the rectangle version
  for(int i = 0;i < pointNum;i++){
    float angle = map(i, 0, pointNum, 0, PI*2);
    setPixel(sin(angle) * radius, cos(angle) * radius);
  }
  xPoints = concat(xPoints, xPointsT);
  yPoints = concat(yPoints, yPointsT);
}
void draw(){
  if(interpolPos > radius){
    pos++;
    interpolPos = 0;
    println(output);
    output = "  !byte ";
  }
  float x=0, y=0;
  float interpolMul = interpolPos / radius;
  x = xPoints[pos] * interpolMul;
  y = yPoints[pos] * interpolMul;
  interpolPos+=1;//sorta the resolution
  background(0);
  
  stroke(255);
  for(int i = 0;i < 2*radius+1;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j < 2*radius+1;j++){
      if((round(x) + radius) == i && (round(y) + radius) == j){
        fill(0, 255, 0);
        if(output != "  !byte ")
          output += ", ";
        output += i-radius;
        output += ", ";
        output += j-radius;
        xPointsHad = append(xPointsHad, i);
        yPointsHad = append(yPointsHad, j);
      }
      else{
        int fillVal = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < xPoints.length;k++){
          if(round(xPoints[k])+radius == i && round(yPoints[k])+radius == j){
            fillVal += 64;
          }
        }
        fill(0, 0, fillVal);
        if(fillVal == 0){
          for(int k = 0; k < xPointsHad.length;k++){
            if(round(xPointsHad[k]) == i && round(yPointsHad[k]) == j){
              fill(128, 0, 0);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      rect(i * tileSize, j * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
    }
  }
  
  strokeWeight(3);
  stroke(0, 255, 255, 64);
  for(int i = 0;i < xPoints.length;i++){
    line((float(radius)+0.5) * tileSize, (float(radius)+0.5) * tileSize, (float(radius)+0.5+xPoints[i]) * tileSize, (float(radius)+0.5+yPoints[i]) * tileSize);
  }
  strokeWeight(1);
  
  fill(255, 255, 0);
  ellipse((x + radius + 0.5) * tileSize, (y + radius + 0.5) * tileSize, 10, 10);
}

void setPixel(float _x, float _y){
  for(int i = 0; i < xPoints.length;i++){
    if(_x == xPoints[i] && _y == yPoints[i]){
      return;
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < xPointsT.length;i++){
    if(_x == xPointsT[i] && _y == yPointsT[i]){
      return;
    }
  }
  
  xPointsT = append(xPointsT, _x);
  yPointsT = append(yPointsT, _y);
}
```

(Instructions to get the rectangle are in the code)
Those mentioned tiles seem to be never hit because the rays on them just jump over them, but what can I do to prevent that? You can decrease interpolPos+=x; to hit more tiles because that way your steps are smaller, but that wastes quite some space, so I don't think that's a good solution. Ideally you could also just decrease the number of coordinates you draw to get a smaller vision. Has anyone a good idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found something that worked for me in my situation: I just used the part that totally works (the rectangle) and then just make that a circle by ignoring every tile hit that's further away from the light source then the radius + 0.5, because without + .5 the circle looks weird. You can try it yourself, here's the code:

```
float[] xPoints = new float[0];
float[] yPoints = new float[0];
float[] xPointsT;
float[] yPointsT;
float[] xPointsHad = new float[0];
float[] yPointsHad = new float[0];
int pos = 0;
float interpolPos = 0;

int radius = 7;
float tileSize = 800.0 / (2*radius+1);

int pointNum = ceil(radius * PI * 2);

String standardOutput = "  !align 15,0\n  !byte ";
void setup() {
  size(800, 800);
  frameRate(60);
  xPointsT = new float[0];
  yPointsT = new float[0];
  for(int i = 0;i <= radius;i++){
    setPixel(radius, i);
    setPixel(i, radius);
  } //Uncomment this and comment the next 4 lines to get the rectangle version
  /*for(int i = 0;i < pointNum;i++){
    float angle = map(i, 0, pointNum, 0, PI*2);
    setPixel(sin(angle) * radius, cos(angle) * radius);
  }*/
  xPoints = concat(xPoints, xPointsT);
  yPoints = concat(yPoints, yPointsT);
  
  xPointsT = new float[0];
  yPointsT = new float[0];
}
void draw(){
  if(interpolPos > radius){
    pos++;
    interpolPos = 0;
    String output = standardOutput;
    for(int i = 0;i < radius + 1;i++){
      int indexPos = floor(map(i, 0, radius + 1, 0, xPointsT.length));
      output += round(xPointsT[indexPos]);
      output += ",";
      output += round(yPointsT[indexPos]);
      if(i < radius){
        output += ", ";
      }
    }
    println(output);
    xPointsT = new float[0];
    yPointsT = new float[0];
  }
  float x=0, y=0;
  float interpolMul = interpolPos / radius;
  x = xPoints[pos] * interpolMul;
  y = yPoints[pos] * interpolMul;
  interpolPos+=1;//sorta the resolution
  background(0);
  
  stroke(255);
  for(int i = 0;i < 2*radius+1;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j < 2*radius+1;j++){
      if((round(x) + radius) == i && (round(y) + radius) == j && sqrt(sq(round(x)) + sq(round(y))) < radius + 0.5){
        fill(0, 255, 0);
        xPointsT = append(xPointsT, i-radius);
        yPointsT = append(yPointsT, j-radius);
        xPointsHad = append(xPointsHad, i);
        yPointsHad = append(yPointsHad, j);
      }
      else{
        int fillVal = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < xPoints.length;k++){
          if(round(xPoints[k])+radius == i && round(yPoints[k])+radius == j){
            fillVal += 64;
          }
        }
        fill(0, 0, fillVal);
        if(fillVal == 0){
          for(int k = 0; k < xPointsHad.length;k++){
            if(round(xPointsHad[k]) == i && round(yPointsHad[k]) == j){
              fill(128, 0, 0);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      rect(i * tileSize, j * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
    }
  }
  
  strokeWeight(3);
  stroke(0, 255, 255, 64);
  for(int i = 0;i < xPoints.length;i++){
    line((float(radius)+0.5) * tileSize, (float(radius)+0.5) * tileSize, (float(radius)+0.5+xPoints[i]) * tileSize, (float(radius)+0.5+yPoints[i]) * tileSize);
  }
  strokeWeight(1);
  
  fill(255, 255, 0);
  ellipse((x + radius + 0.5) * tileSize, (y + radius + 0.5) * tileSize, 10, 10);
}

void setPixel(float _x, float _y){
  for(int i = 0; i < xPoints.length;i++){
    if(_x == xPoints[i] && _y == yPoints[i]){
      return;
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < xPointsT.length;i++){
    if(_x == xPointsT[i] && _y == yPointsT[i]){
      return;
    }
  }
  
  xPointsT = append(xPointsT, _x);
  yPointsT = append(yPointsT, _y);
}
```

Besides the main difference to ignore tiles that are not in the circle, I also changed that I store the coordinates not in a String but in two arrays, because then I use code to stretch them when there are fewer then radius + 1 points, so I don't have to store multiple circles with different sizes in the C64's RAM, so it meets my main requirements: It should fill every tile and it should be downscalable by ignoring some points at the end of rays. And is if efficient? Uh ... there could be a better solution that fills the circle with fewer rays, but I don't care too much. Still, if you have an idea, it would be nice if you could tell me, but otherwise this question is solved.

Edit: I forgot to add a picture. Don't be confused, I modified the code after posting it so you can also see the blue tiles on the circle.

[image: Filled circle]

Answer (score 4):

You have chosen wrong  method to find all touched cells - instead of point-based way you need cell(squares)-based approach - ray intersects rectangle rather than point.

[There is article](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/%7Eamana/research/grid.pdf) of Amanatides and Woo "A Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithm for Ray Tracing" for 2D.

[Practical implementation](https://www.flipcode.com/archives/Raytracing_Topics_Techniques-Part_4_Spatial_Subdivisions.shtml).

Example:

[image]

Quick-made tracing example. Rays emitted from left top corner go to blue points. If ray meets black cell obstacle, it stops. Pink cells are lighted by rays, grey ones are not.

[image]

Comment: I didn't use Bresenham and the normal way of filling circles because the lines have to start at the center. I don't know if you read the entire post (I can understand if you didn't) but I want to simulate how light spreads, using vertical or horizontal lines aren't too great in this case, and I wanted to have float results for the circle instead of the int values the circle Bresenham creates. Also, aren't pixels squares and voxels cubes? And I don't quite get how you can detect the blue squares.

Comment: Yes, I did read the entire post but was not sure that lines must go from center. OK, I 'll remove the second part of post. Perhaps I made wrong contradiction - just wanted to emphasize that you cannot mark cells checking points like this `if(round(xPoints[k])+radius == i && round(yPoints[k])+radius == j)`

Comment: Okay, but how exactly can I detect the blue tiles?

Comment: Blur squares are touched but not intersected through edges (I needed to separate these cases). Perhaps you don't need them. Such cells are registered when ray goes through grid point (also I separated cases of horizontal and vertical line along edge)

Comment: Oh. I thought that you wanted to tell me that I need to detect those to get rid of the missing tiles. So what could I use instead of `if(round(xPoints[k])+radius == i && round(yPoints[k])+radius == j)`?

Comment: You build line from starting point to ending one described by initial position and direction vector (dx,dy). Then you find intersection of line with cell edges step-by-step using method from linled paper.

Comment: Being properly implemented - this method will not miss tiles

Comment: So how exactly would a code implementation of that look? Also, would that cause different lines to intersect a different amount of tiles? That would be pretty bad since that way I can't just ignore a given amount of points to reduce the vision and it would make the whole assembler code more complicated and slower.

Comment: Second link contains a pieces of implementation (in 3D). Different lines do intersect different amount of tiles, but seems your lines do the same.

Comment: I don't quite get what BFS is and especially not how that should help me in my situation.

Comment: Uh, okay. But currently I have an idea, maybe I can just use my old rectangle, remove tiles to make it a circle and then strech the coordinates so the distance is always 1 between two points. Gotta try that in 15 minutes when I am allowed to use my PC again ...

Comment: Alright, I think I found a way: I just used the rectangle but just ignored every point with a bigger distance then the radius.

Comment: @NoobTracker Hello again! If this answer helped you in any way, I suggest that you upvote it. If it helped solve your issue, please mark it as the solution. If you found an different solution on your own or inspired by this answer, please write your solution to this post as an answer and mark it as solved. Theses actions will help future users with a similar issue to find your post and learn from it. Fantastic re-writing btw.

Comment: @laancelot I currently still code on it (I live in Germany and my parents don't want me to use my PC after 7:30 pm for some reason, that's why I was interrupted) but I think I'm on the right way and can share a maybe not perfect but working solution in a few hours.

Comment: Okay, I posted my answer, but I have to wait for one day until I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: Okay, now I was finally able to mark my answer as the solution.